# How to write QVector fo txt file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write QVector that consists of objects of my class to file and have some problems with it. I need to save some objects to .txt file, then read them out. But saving doesn't work correctly. What is the way i can release it?

Film.h

```
class Film
{
public:
    QString title;
    int year;
    friend QDataStream &operator<< (QDataStream &stream, const Film obj)
    {
        stream << obj.title; //title only while i'm testing my program
        return stream;
    }
    friend QDataStream &operator>> (QDataStream &stream, Film &obj)
    {
        stream >> obj.title;
        return stream;
    }
};
```

AddFilm.cpp

```
void AddFilm::slotOkButtonClicked()
{
    QVector<Film> database;
    Film film;
    film.title = titleLine->text(); // QLineEdit where i input data
    film.year = yearLine->text().toInt(); // QLineEdit where i input data
    database.push_back(film);
    QFile file("database.fdtb");
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QDataStream out(&file);
        out << film;
        file.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register the stream operators of your class somewhere in your code when starting your application before streaming the class. This could be done in the constructor of your main window :

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<Film>("Film");
```

Now you can save or load objects of your class to or from file.

Saving some objects of your custom classes to a file :

```
QFile file(fileName);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
         QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"),
             file.errorString());
         return;
 }


 QDataStream out(&file);
 out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
 out << object1;
```

loading objects of your custom classes from a file :

```
QFile file(fileName);
 if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
         QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"),
             file.errorString());
         return;
 }


  QDataStream in(&file);
  in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
  in >> object1;
```

You can also use `QSettings` to save an object in your application :

```
QSettings settings("organizationName","applicationName");
settings.setValue("settings/ّFilm",QVariant(film));
```

Or read them :

```
Film film = settings.value(QString("settings/film")).value<Film>();
```

`Film` should inherit from `QObject` and should have public default and copy constructors and a public destructor. You should also have the macro `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Film)`.

In case it is necessary to use files, you can define a file name for your `QSettings` :

```
settings=new QSettings("Mysettings/film.ini", QSettings::IniFormat,this);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but i still have a little problem. I want to write a qvector to file, not one object. My program shows me element 0 in vector, but when i want to see the next one, i have an error with "index out of range". I tried to use your code with qvector:
QVector<Film> base;
...
base.push_back(film);
...
out << base;

Comment: If you only push one item in the vector them how do you want to access the next item?

Comment: I pushed some objects in vector. i'm starting my program, go to Add film and call slot okButtonClicked (that push object to vector and save vector to file) about 5 times. So i think there should be 5 objects in vector, no?

Comment: Try to see `count()` of vector in debug mode to check if it really has 5 elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i really appreciate it.. I think i got solution of my problem, i will try to solve it later.